# How can I deploy Next js app on cpanel hosting

Tags: javascript, express, cpanel, web-deployment, next.js

I am trying to deploy next js app on cPanel. I have installed node and npm on it.
How can I deploy the next js app on this set up?

I am getting the following error while trying to build the app on cpanel terminal:

**Unhandled rejection TypeError: child.send is not a function**

Comment: To deploy Next.js app, at first you need to execute build script (`npm run build`) which is defined in package.json and `npm run start`. But currently it is not possible to run  custom scripts with PussionPassanger which is used in cPanel. It works only by taking `app.js` file as entrypoint.

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: @LaurisKuznecovs which `app.js` you mean?do i have to select it as `Application startup file` when creating nodejs application?

Comment: @BehnamEsmaili I don't think it's possible unless you have some kind of elevated access (*like root*) and you definitely going to need SSH access. Check this article [How to Install a Node.js Application](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Install+a+Node.js+Application). I deploy all node applications using Plesk panel.

Answer (score 3):

You should run `next export` to make static html and js files in `out` you can directly upload it to Cpanel as normal html website
you can run `npm run export` or `yarn export` by adding

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "export": "next export"
  },
```

these in package.json

Comment: downside with this approach is server databinding not working.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need root privileges. If you've got them you can remote into your server via SSH and run the npm commands there. Then it should work. I.e, from console:

```
ssh user@serverip
cd /path/to/appdirectory
npm run start
```

Comment: in shared hosting root privilage is not available.

Comment: See "you'll need root privileges." I don't believe it's possible to do this at all without them, but I could be mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

There are some options to deploy NextJS app in CPanel:

1. You just deploy serverless app (without NodeJS) in CPanel. NextJS has provided a syntax like `next export` to producing optimized frontend files.
2. New version of CPanel already has entry point for your nodejs application:
   [image: Entry point of NodeJS app in CPanel] Specify your server file on that field.

Comment: What file is the entry point for a nextjs application?

Comment: you can define your server file if you use NextJS with server. otherwise just point to your index for serverless NextJS app

Answer (score 1):

Next.js applications *should* run fine on a web hosting provider using cPanel, but running the default next.js server tends to exceed process count and memory quotas applied by those types of providers.

However you can make hosting next.js apps work if you build a production version of your app elsewhere and then use a custom server to call your next.js app to handle incoming requests.

I describe the process to deploy a very basic application as a subsite on my website here - https://www.watfordconsulting.com/2021/02/08/deploy-next-js-applications-to-a-cpanel-web-host/

Answer (score 0):

All you really need to do is run `next export` and put the contents of the `out` folder in the public_html folder or `/var/www/html/`, `/sites-available/`, etc, depending on setup.