# How to deploy next js 14 with app router cPanel

Tags: node.js, cpanel, next.js13

How can I successfully deploy my `Next.js 14` project, which utilizes the `app router` and relies on a `PHP API`, onto a `cPanel` hosting environment? I've noticed that most deployment tutorials are geared towards Next.js projects using the `pages router`, but my project is dynamic, making it incompatible with the `npm run export` method.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56424836/how-can-i-deploy-next-js-app-on-cpanel-hosting) could not help me.

And The other question is: what do I have to write in `Application startup file`?
[image]

I would appreciate it if you could step by step tell me what I need to do.

Comment: @sajalsuraj no, I deployed on another server.

Comment: Ok, which is cheap and best suitable server to host nextjs apps? Can you suggest a few

Comment: I have no idea about international server. I'm using https://liara.ir/.